# inserting new record in the msaccess using dataset

Tags: vb.net, dataset, addition, record

I am trying to insert a new record into msaccess2003 mdb file my version is VB.net 2005, it doesnt show any error and also when i open my access db file, there is no record inserted, And also how can i format the date field it is giving me error, how can i convert the txtdate.text to date compatible with ms acess

here is the code

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim db As New ClassDB

    ds = db.FetchData("ricemill.mdb", "sales")


    Dim anyRow As DataRow = ds.Tables(0).NewRow
    Dim mydate As DateTime
    Dim cmydate As String

    cmydate = txtdate.Text
    mydate = DateTime.Parse(mydate)


    anyRow("description") = txtdesc.Text
    anyRow("date") = DateTime.Parse(txtdate.Text)
    anyRow("amount") = txtamount.Text



    ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(anyRow)
    ds.Tables(0).AcceptChanges()
    ds.AcceptChanges()

    MsgBox("Record Added ! ")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

ok well, I can give you a hint to start ( even though this is an old thread ) I wouldve find this usefull if I had stumble into this when I started my projet a month ago.

what you have done here is you created a new row virtually, and add it to your virtual database ( the dataset )

the acceptchanges method only change the relation of your row vs your dataset, it will commit the change so your dataset will consider the row not as a newly created row, but as a regular row.

what you want here is to open a connection, use an Update command on a dataAdapter, so it ( the DA) will look at all the changes in your dataset and commit them to the actual database.

it took me a while to get it working, most if it was testing and error and reading tons of blog/internet info.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6264xxbd.aspx

start here and once you understand the DA you'll be very close to your answer.